# A href tag takes up the whole div

Tags: html, css

I wanted  to create a link for my logo in the footer, I centered the logo via `display:block` and `margin: 0 auto`, but when I did so, the `a href` tag took up the whole footer, like I set the width to 100% or something.

**Here's the css sample**

```
#footer{
height:60px;
position:absolute;
background-color:white;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
left:0;
}

#logo{
text-align:center;
width:50px;
height:auto; 
bottom:0px;
padding-top:10px;
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
}
```

**HTML(JADE Template Engine was used)**

```
 div#footer  
    a#gitlink(href='https://github.com/ZippoRays/slatkatajnamk2')
        img#logo(src='randomimg')
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML.

Comment: How can I override the display:block declaration? Since I can't seem to center the logo otherwise?

Comment: Could you please post some html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS to something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/0fqvf9oe/

I.e. give your anchor the `display:block;` property and not the image:

```
#footer a {
    display:block;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, just throws the image off its centered position :(

Comment: Check out the JSFIddle, it's in there.

Comment: It works in the JSFiddle, however, I have to keep the `width:50px` and `height:auto` properties to the image, because if I remove them, the image gets to its original size, those were used to resize it. But still, when I remove everything else and I copied your code onto my **a** tag, it still did nothing. The image remained centered tho, but the `a href` is still taking up the whole footer.

Comment: Make a JSFiddle of your own, post it here, and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I have no clue as to what's going on. It works just fine when I copy it into JSFiddle and transform JADE into pure HTML. Still, thanks a lot for your support mate.

Comment: No problem. Consider upvoting :)

Comment: Tried to, apparently I don't have enough reputation, I'm a total newbie here :D